# How to resolve - IE 6 ignores img "width" properties

Tags: images, html

In this post:

http://humus101.com/?p=1734

We've got 4 images set (in the img property) to a width of 246 pixel.

In chrome it looks fine.  In IE6 it doesn't.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: This is not related specifically to the twentyten theme, I suggest you remove that from the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

In the style.css

I needed to make the following change

```
#content img {
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 640px;
    /*width: auto;*/
}
```

I now wonder how to make that stay for all the following theme updates...

Comment: By creating a child theme ;) That's preserved while the parent theme get's updated. Would this make sense?

Comment: It makes sense.  I tried doing it - but failed somehow.  I'll play with it more, and if fail again - will return to ask :)

Answer (score 2):

The height attribute of the image is missing. So I would not wonder about differences in display between browsers, because [HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#adef-width-IMG) specs do not clearly define how to deal with such a situation.

How to deal with that? Hook into the theme / wp core and patch the code that next to the width attribute, the height attribute is calculated and used as well.

Comment: Interesting!  But I don't know how to do that.  Any suggestions ?

Comment: How do you enter those four images into the post?

Comment: I used an HTML table (with a plugin that helped construct it)

Comment: And why does that plugin does not use a _width_ **and** _height_ attribute for your images? Link to that plug?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  I am using the default image unloader to get the images. I am simply organizing them inside a table to have a square layout.

Comment: And while doing the last part of it (simply organizing them inside a table to have a square layout), the _default_ inserting containing width and height get's crippled and the height attribute removed. The main problem with the display is that the height attribute get's removed therefore leaving the browser to jump in to decide how to deal with the height not set, e.g. taking 100% or some original height of the file.

Comment: I actually removed the height manually, since I wanted to resize the images to a specific size.

Comment: So you removed the height attribute and modified the width attribute to match your width? No wonder that this does not work. You need to leave the height attribute in there and _calculate_ the right height in size. It might be helpful that you enter your wished width/height combo into the thumbnail settings: http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Media_SubPanel and then just use the pre-sized thumbnail images.

Comment: Thanks Hakre.

The author of that blog is not me, I'm just it's maintainer.  So is the CSS solution the right way to have it be accepted?

Comment: `height: auto;` might just make IE to re-calculate the height and therefore fixes your display problem. So if it does the job, why not? In case it breaks again you would need to find something more robust anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If 640 px is the width you want. I would go into wordpress and set that up as one of the sizes for the images; and then when you want to insert one into a post, select the that size.

Under Settings->Media you can set the Medium and Large sizes. I would change these to what you want; then use this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bulk-image-resize-utility/ which will resize the images you have.

What wordpress will do is create new images with these dimensions. What this does for the user, is they are only downloading the size of the image that the are seeing, which helps page load time.

You might have to go back into your post and edit the images to use the medium or large size.

Answer (score 0):

```
#content img {
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 640px;
    width: auto;
}
```

The above puzzles me terrible, I did remove `width: auto;` in TwentyTen theme, it worked - but as for the child tbeme option, how does one leave out the line in child theme, but is still used via parent theme, its weird!

I though the child theme style sheet replace use of TwentyTen theme.